# How can I create a pull request in GitHub Action when my test fail?

Tags: python, github, workflow, github-actions, pull-request

```
name: Python package

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install flake8 pytest 
          if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
      - name: Lint with flake8
        run: |
          # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
          flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
          # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
          flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
      - name: Test with unittest
        run: |
          python test_rows.py
          python test_number_neighbors.py
```

Here is my workflow code.
As I understand, every time push or pull-request happens - it runs test_rows.py and test_number_neighbors.py. What I need is to separate tests that fail from tests that pass ( fail tests should go into other pull-request (for example, called FAILED_TESTS) and it should be done automatically . Is there any option to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can return non-zero exit code in your test step and then create a PR with next step that would run only if previous failed. Here's a simple example:

```
name: Status check

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Test
        run: exit 1
      - name: Status check
        if: ${{ failure() }}
        run: echo Previous step failed!
```

To create a PR, you can use [gh CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/) (it's available on runnrer), [script action](https://github.com/actions/github-script) or use any other custom actions for PR (plenty available already).